# Restore default completion

Tags: bash, arch-linux, autocomplete

I use `compgen` when `$COMP_WORD` equals 1, now I want to restore default completion when otherwise,

Right now I have,

```
_rr()
{
    case $COMP_CWORD in
        1)
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "A B" "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"))
            ;;
    esac
}

complete -F _rr rr
```

Now when `$COMP_CWORD` is not 1, I got no completion for files / directories, that's the default completion I needed.

Also I need to enable completion only when `${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD - 1]}` is `A` in this minimal case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that in your real-world case you want to do other things too, and so continue to use `case` constructs (although in this minimal case, `if` constructs would have been sufficient):

```
_rr()
{
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD - 1]}"

    case "${COMP_CWORD}" in
        1)
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "A B" "${cur}"))
            ;;
    esac

    case "${prev}" in
        A)
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f "${cur}"))
            ;;
    esac
}

complete -F _rr rr
```

Documentation of the `-f` option to `compgen` is available in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) (scroll down to `file`, under the `-A action` subsection of the description of the `complete` builtin).

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19062943/807650) provides a better alternative using the `-o default` option from `complete`